# Uploading DSYMs files for Fabric Craslytics Automatically

Tags: crashlytics

I am trying to upload all DSYMs files while creating .ipa file for Enterprise release not for ITunes release. I am able to upload all my file manually and when I did that it's works fine but still showing missing DSYMs and also when I created new .ipa file again Fabric is not showing crash reports.

can any one help me how to upload DSYMs file automatically for every build and when creating .ipa files. if i have to write script please let me know where do i have to..

Comment: This can happen for a variety of different reasons, but the most common issue is when using static frameworks. If you have static frameworks, make sure you have the following set:"Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" -> NO
"Strip Linked Product" -> NO

Comment: Mike, Thanks for that tip but i already have NO for those two... but it is still showing Missing DSYMs uuid in optional tab.. Well I know it's optional but i am looking for better solution to keep every DSYMs file for every build and for every .ipa file in it..

Comment: Thanks for that context. How are you distributing to your customers?

Comment: I am doing Enterprise Distribution for App release.

Comment: Ok, so manually distributing then. If you search for the dSYM when building on any of the build servers, do you find it? If not, then there is a build setting that will need to be changed.

Comment: yes . I do find All dSYM file .. but any way can i know that build setting to be make sure..

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your build settings after filtering on "Strip"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158550/discussion-between-ttt-and-mike-bonnell).